# Is there a way in eclipse to get the compare tool to only show you matching files?

Tags: eclipse, compare

I frequently have to diff two trees of source files, one coming from svn (in which you can only check out the whole tree) and the other my eclipse workspace.
99% of the time I only want to see diffs in files that are in both compare trees. The svn side has thousands of files my workspace does not, and I don't need to see them.
Is there a way to get the compare utility to only show files that exist on both sides, and skip the ones it would put the little minus icon on?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to carefully select only the files and folders you want included in the comparison, then right-click and choose **Team** > **Synchronize with Repository**.

[image]

That will open the Synchronize perspective and show a Inbound/Outbound view of changes. From there you can "pin" the synchronization and later come back to it and re-sync to see updated results.

[image]

You can read some more about the Synchronize view at http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not actually using the compare to compare with something in svn that was checked out with eclipse.

Comment: I use two version control systems. one for me, and one for the company build. So when I want to compare my changes with the company build I just do a compare on the head of the source tree for my eclipse project and a linked folder pointing to the checkout of the company build. But the company build has tons of stuff that my eclipse checkout doesn't (way too big to load into eclipse or I'd do it that way)